# Issue when build classpath with batch loop when path having space

Tags: java, batch-file

I had spent some times to solve the issue. My goal is just to build the java classpath by using batch file loop through directories.

Here is my program:

```
@echo off

@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"

set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
setx STSPOS_PS "%CURRENT_DIR%" /m
set "BIN=%CURRENT_DIR%\bin"
set "LIB=%CURRENT_DIR%\lib"
set "LOG=%CURRENT_DIR%\log"
set "jdk=%CURRENT_DIR%\jdk"
setx JAVA_HOME "%JDK%" /m

FOR %%X in ("%LIB%\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\lib\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\jre\lib\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\jre\lib\ext\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

%BIN%/service.bat
echo %CLASSPATH%
GOTO :EOF

:AddToPath
SET CLASSPATH=%~1;%CLASSPATH%
:EOF
```

Issue that I encounter is when the directories contain space in path, then the program will encounter error as "uncrecognize c:\project command not found" if I run the batch file in folder "C:\project abc".

If without space in path, it's work as expected.

Would appreciate somebody can provide solution on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

quotes are your [saviour](http://www.digizol.com/2006/12/setting-java-classpath-option-with.html)

```
@echo off

@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"

set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
setx STSPOS_PS "%CURRENT_DIR%" /m
set "BIN=%CURRENT_DIR%\bin"
set "LIB=%CURRENT_DIR%\lib"
set "LOG=%CURRENT_DIR%\log"
set "jdk=%CURRENT_DIR%\jdk"
setx JAVA_HOME "%JDK%" /m

FOR %%X in ("%LIB%\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\lib\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\jre\lib\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

FOR %%X in ("%JDK%\jre\lib\ext\*.jar") DO CALL :AddToPath "%%~dpnfX"

%BIN%/service.bat
echo %CLASSPATH%
GOTO :EOF

:AddToPath
SET "CLASSPATH="%~1";%CLASSPATH%"
:EOF
```

though I would use `for /r` and delayed expansion so everything could be done with one loop and without subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution after I done further research.

I change the line

```
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
```

to

```
FOR %%F in ("%cd%") DO set "CURRENT_DIR=%%~sF"
```

so the output will be "C:\project abc" to "C:\projec~1".

Thanks.

Comment: short paths are not always enabled , but is a viable solution.